How can I define the pdf of a Multivariate Log Normal Distribution using scipy classes?
I am looking to sample from the multivariate log normal distribution by using the class multivar_normal_gen in the scipy module. My strategy was to simply re-define the log multivariate normal pdf using the _logpdf method and then pass that into _dist in multivariate_normal_frozen class.
The form of the pdf is defined in this StackExchange post.
from typing import Dict, Union, List, Optional
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import Covariance
from scipy.stats._multivariate import multivariate_normal_frozen, multivariate_normal_gen
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

_LOG_2PI = np.log(2 * np.pi)


class MultivariateNormalLogGen(multivariate_normal_gen):
    def _logpdf(self, x: np.array, mean: np.array, cov_object: Covariance) -> np.array:
        log_det_cov, rank = cov_object.log_pdet, cov_object.rank
        dev = np.log(x) - mean
        if dev.ndim > 1:
            log_det_cov = log_det_cov[..., np.newaxis]
            rank = rank[..., np.newaxis]
        maha = np.sum(np.square(cov_object.whiten(dev)) + 2 * np.log(x), axis=-1)

        return -0.5 * (rank * _LOG_2PI + log_det_cov + maha)


class MultivariateNormalLogFrozen(multivariate_normal_frozen):
    _dist = MultivariateNormalLogGen()

However, this does not result in the desired distribution as the limits are not between 0 and positive infinity. Below it's an example that uses the class methods and plots a supposedly bivariate log normal distribution.
class BivariateNormal(MultivariateNormalLogFrozen):

    def __init__(self,
                 parameter_names: List[str],
                 mu: np.array,
                 cov: Union[np.array, Covariance]):
        super(BivariateLogNormal, self).__init__(mean=mu, cov=cov)
        self.parameter_names = parameter_names
        self.mu_data = mu
        self.cov_data = cov

    def draw_sample(self, n: int, seed: Optional[int] = None) -> Dict[str, np.array]:
        """Draws samples from the distribution."""
        if seed:
            np.random.seed(seed)
        sample = self.rvs(n)  # np.exp(self.rvs(n))
        result = {}
        for j, par in enumerate(self.parameter_names):
            result[par] = sample[:, j]
        return result


def plot_distribution(
    dsn: BivariateLogNormal,
    sample: Dict[str, np.array]
) -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6))
    color = "tab:blue"
    cmap = "Blues"
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)
    ax.plot(
        df['par_1'], df['par_2'],
        '*',
        color=color,
        markeredgecolor='k',
        markersize=10,
    )

    # plot pdf
    xlims = ax.get_xlim()
    ylims = ax.get_ylim()
    xvec = np.linspace(start=xlims[0], stop=xlims[1], num=100)
    yvec = np.linspace(start=ylims[0], stop=ylims[1], num=100)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(xvec, yvec)
    xy = np.dstack((x, y))
    z = dsn.pdf(xy)  # FIXME: Change to lognormal pdf
    ax.contour(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, levels=100)
    ax.set_xlabel('parameter_1')
    ax.set_ylabel('parameter_2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    seed = 124
    n_samples = 50

    # sampling from distribution
    parameter_names = ['par_1', 'par_2']

    mu = np.log(np.array([0.5, 0.5]))
    cov = np.array([
        [1.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 1.0]
    ])
    dsn = BivariateLogNormal(mu=mu, cov=cov, parameter_names=parameter_names)
    sample = dsn.draw_sample(n_samples, seed=seed)

    # plot distributions
    plot_distribution(
        dsn=dsn,
        sample=sample,
    )


bivariate_normal_dsn
How can I achieve this properly? Should I define other methods like _pdf instead? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

You wrote that you want to sample from the distribution, right? Typically, "lognormal" describes a random variable whose logarithm is normally distributed. So to sample from the univariate lognormal distribution, you can sample x from the normal distribution and take exp(x). This is what would need to be extended to multiple dimensions.
In any case, SciPy's multivariate infrastructure won't help you here. You don't even need to define the PDF if all you want to do is sample from it (although there are ways of sampling given a PDF, like ratio of uniforms and such).

After Matt's answer, here is my workaround on the pdf and the sampling from a Multivariate Log Normal. Not super smart, but it works.
from typing import Dict, List, Optional
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import Covariance, multivariate_normal

_LOG_2PI = np.log(2 * np.pi)

class BivariateLogNormal:

    def __init__(self, 
                 parameter_names: List[str], 
                 mean: np.array, 
                 cov: Covariance) -> None:
        self.parameter_names = parameter_names
        self.mean = mean
        self.cov = cov

    def rvs(self, 
            size: int, 
            seed: Optional[int]) -> Dict[str, np.array]:

        if seed:
            np.random.seed(seed)

        multi_norm = multivariate_normal(self.mean, self.cov)
        sample = np.exp(multi_norm.rvs(size=size))

        result = {}
        for j, par in enumerate(self.parameter_names):
            result[par] = sample[:, j]

        return result

    def logpdf(self,  
               x: np.array) -> np.array:
        log_det_cov, rank = self.cov.log_pdet, self.cov.rank
        dev = np.log(x) - self.mean
        if dev.ndim > 1:
            log_det_cov = log_det_cov[..., np.newaxis]
            rank = rank[..., np.newaxis]
        maha = np.sum(np.square(self.cov.whiten(dev)) + 2 * np.log(x), axis=-1)

        return -0.5 * (rank * _LOG_2PI + log_det_cov + maha)

    def pdf(self, 
            x: np.array) -> np.array:
        return np.exp(self.logpdf(x))




I am looking to sample from the multivariate log normal distribution

According to the Wikipedia article Log-normal distribution,

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(89435894365823)
cov = stats.Covariance.from_diagonal([1, 2, 3])
mean = [4, 5, 6]
X = stats.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)  # define multivariate normal
x = X.rvs()  # sample from it
y = np.exp(x)  # exponentiate elementwise
# y is a sample from a multivariate log-normal distribution

I would recommend against using SciPy's multivariate distribution infrastructure. It is barely an "infrastructure"; it provides little more than input validation of a NumPy PRNG and some tools for documentation (and that part of it is confusing). Feel free to create a class that defines objects with a similar interface, though. For instance, you might want create a class to represent the distribution with an initializer that accepts the mean and covariance. Then, instances of the class represent random variables (like "frozen" distributions), and it could have a method to perform random sampling. The new univariate continuous distribution infrastructure just merged; I'll probably work on the multivariate distribution infrastructure after finishing discrete distributions and some other features of the univariate infrastructure (mixture distributions, truncated distributions, wrapped distributions, etc.).

Thanks for the breakdown and the advice. As you have stated, sampling is quite straightforward. I guess I will define the pdf outside of scipy class structure and be done with it. Thanks again for your time!
